# Why is my instagram api fetching data returning false instead of a json object?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to use the instagram api on a wordpress page. Given the following function to get the data, would anyone please point me why is my var_dump($results) return boolean false???

```
function fetchData($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
}


$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{{userId}}/media/recent/?access_token={{accessToken}}&count=20");

var_dump($result);
```

note: {{userId}} & {{accessToken}} are placeholders. On my code Im using the real id and token instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, Instagram Server will return

```
{"pagination":{....},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[.......]}
```

I think there is a SSL error, try to add this line below CURLOPT_TIMEOUT

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

About SSL error

[cURL PHP RESTful service always returning FALSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657382/curl-php-restful-service-always-returning-false)

You can try curl_error() and curl_errno() to debug cURL functions

[curl_exec() always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227909/curl-exec-always-returns-false)