# Images with https in mpdf

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, mpdf

I am using MPDF to generate a pdf with images. With http:// all works fine, but after changing my whole site to https:// I only get red crosses where the images should appear.

If I watch the generated file as html version, the images are all there, with https://, but in the generated PDF they are just not shown.

Any hint?

UPDATE:
Error was because of CURL
("SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate")

It was resolved by adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`
to mpdf.php

Answer was found here:
[curl: (60) SSL certificate : unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Dirty Way: [cURL PHP RESTful service always returning FALSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657382/curl-php-restful-service-always-returning-false)

Answer (score 13):

For anyone coming here from Google - there is now a better solution.  mPDF now supports setting curlAllowUnsafeSslRequests.

```
$mdf = new Mpdf(<your configuration>);
$mpdf->curlAllowUnsafeSslRequests = true;
```

This will set the CURL parameters properly for you without having to modify mPDF. 
 Obviously, use only in appropriate situations, as this disables SSL all verification protections.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you need to remove the protocol from URL for this I have created a plugin please install it and activate.

Here is the plugin link:- https://wordpress.org/plugins/vg-protocol-removed-not-secure-connection/

Comment: thanks for your answer - but sadly this does not resolve the problem. I am already using the "Really Simple SSL" addon, to keep all URLs https://. In webview the images are shown correctly (with https:// in front), but in PDF view, they are not visible (only red crosses)

Comment: Can you attached the screenshot

Comment: You need to regenerate the pdf Thumbnails for regenerate the PDF thumbnails please visit the link: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-regenerate-pdf-thumbnails-in-wordpress/

Comment: How should this be connected to the issue?

Comment: you site PDF thumbnails is missing, so you need to regenerate the thumbnails.

Comment: Please see updated question on how it was finally solved

Answer (score 0):

If you have a root cert, it's preferable to provide it using CURLOPT_CAINFO or CURLOPT_CAPATH than to bypass validation altogether.

It is a shame mPDF isn't designed better so you could avoid modifying the library code directly.